# how to use markdown formatting in gt::cols_label when supplying names with .list argument

Tags: r, gt

Hello stackoverflow community,

I'd like to use the function for column renaming `gt:cols_label()` and globally define a list for this to input to the `.list`-argument of `gt:cols_label()`. The list should contain:

- the new column names
- the desired formatting options (using the `md()`-Function)

While providing both info in the `...`-argument directly works:

```
mpg %>%
  gt::gt() %>%
  gt::cols_label(
    manufacturer = md("*M*a**nufac***ture***r**")
  )
```

This does not (and neither does the commented try):

```
rename_format_cols <- c(
  "manufacturer" = md("*M*a**nufac***ture***r**")
  ) %>%
  as.list()

# rename_format_cols <- c(
#  "manufacturer" = "md("*M*a**nufac***ture***r**")"
#   ) %>%
#   as.list()

mpg %>%
  gt::gt() %>%
  gt::cols_label(
    .list = rename_format_cols
  )
```

I'd be very glad if you'd helped out.

Best regards, paulge